# Multiple lines in HTML submit button on iPad

Tags: html, css

I have the following on an existing site - the `'&#10;'` creates a multi-lined button - I need the text to appear on multiple lines in button ('button1' feeds of the CSS to create button with rounded edges)

All is find and dandy with multi-lined button appearing in desk/lap-top browsers **except** when viewed via iPad safari - only the first line of the button appears in iPad's safari browser.

Do you have any tips on how this can work in iPad browser as well?

```
<INPUT id="button1" type="submit" VALUE="I wish to update my &#10;legal name" tabindex="1">
```

Comment: Can you set the height of the button?

Comment: If you really want to control the style of it, use a button tag or anchor - something you can have more control over. `&#10;` inside the `value` property seems like a really hacky way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Would a `div` or `a` be okay? Using css, you could style it like a submit button, and javascript can be used to make it act like a submit button.